# How to assemble Offset function with Condition?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2016

I Have date data in Column A and values data in Column B.

My aim goal is that for each date in column A : 
look if one value (column B) during 1 year is less than 90% of the corresponding Value of the date.

This is my data:

[image]

**Output example :**

I start at the first date (31/12/1986) and see the 900.82 value.
I calcul 900.82 * 0.9 = 810.73
So i look if value in line 3 is inferior to 810.73,

- If not

I look if value in line 4 is inferior to 810.73,
line 5, 6, 7 ,8..... during 1 year (that mean I stop this the 31/12/1987).

- If it is

I stop and i look the next date (01/01/1987) and do the same.

I am agree to translate it in VBA code, but it could be better on Excel.

I first tried an algo to understand the problem :

```
-Look the first date in column A
-Look the corresponding value in Column B and save it as Value
-Offset to the next date in column A
-Look the corresponding value in Column B and save it as Range.to.compare
-If Range.to.compare < Value * 90% then write "ok" in Column C
-Else, Offset to the next date in column A...
-Untill 1 Year (Untill Year(Date in Column A)<Year(Date in Column A) +1
```

I try to translate it in Excel or VBA.

This this what I tried by Excel :

[image: First excel try]

But it works only for 1 day instead of 1 year

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please poste the code you have tried. Also, an output example would help the question.

Comment: Can you restate this? - "My aim goal is that for each date in column A : look if one value (column B) during 1 year is less than 90% of the corresponding Value of the date."  I'm not totally clear on what you're wanting it to do.  Example output could help too.

Comment: Thank you for you help, all is edited

Comment: Why are you using `OFFSET` in your formulas? `=IF(B2>B3,"ok", B3)` would accomplish the same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're after.  I broke the calculation into multiple columns to show the steps.

First I calculate the 90% value, in column C.

[image: Column C formula]

Column D is where most of the magic happens.  In column D I find all rows that have a date < the current date + 1 year, and get the value (Col B) for each of those rows.  I then take the minimum of all those values.  Note this is an array formula so you need to press shift-ctrl-enter after you type it in.

[image: Column D formula]

Now that I have the minimum from the each range, I just need to compare that with the 90% value.

[image: Column E formula]